# How to use the function in springboard server?

Tags: iphone, jailbreak

I want to use the function "Reboot()" in the app with the springboardserver.framework,But when i add the private framework and the headers of springboardserver, the error will appear.

the reboot() is in the springboardserver.framework,the info about the springboardserver.framework function.
http://iphonedevwiki.net/index.php/SpringBoard.app/MIG_subsystem

I want to know how to use the function like this.Thank you for your  help.

Comment: Well, first off, ***what is the error***?

Answer (score 0):

there is a function called SBReboot() (not sure about the function arguments) in SpringBoardServices.framework